# Pulling images from a directory with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm outputting data from a mysql table into an HTML table but also wanting to pull images from a directory to display with each row.

For each row I want to add an image from the directory where the name coresponds to the id number of the mysql row, i.e. the mysql output row of 'ID 1' would show the image '1.jpeg'.

I'm using this to pull all of the images which I've found on Stackoverflow which works fine for all images.

```
$string =array();
$filePath='lot_images/';  
$dir = opendir($filePath);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) { 
if (eregi("\.png",$file) || eregi("\.jpg",$file) || eregi("\.gif",$file) ) { 
$string[] = $file;
}
}
while (sizeof($string) != 0){
$img = array_pop($string);  
echo "<img src='$filePath$img'  width='100px'/>";  
}
```

just a nod in the right direction or what to learn and read up on a I'm new to php.

cheers

Comment: This script has nothing to do with pulling an image from a row.. What you want to do is store the image path in the row and the use that data to construct the src path for the image.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Sorry I didn't eplain properly, the database is prepopulated and the images have been ftp'd to the server by two seperate parties so I'm in the middle trying to pull them out onto a webpage. Your way would be the obvious choice if i was creating the DB from scratch but that's why I wanted to use something like the above script but adapt it to work how I explained.

Comment: The above script still has nothing to do with databases, what did you try so ar?

Comment: I know it doesn't its just pulling out all images from the directory that's what I'm trying to say but obviously not very well. The images are not referenced in the database at all, I'm doing the usual simple select to pull out all of the input from the DB i.e. ID, description, price etc to form an html table but as the images are not referenced in the DB I need some way to marry up the ID number with the image name from the directory they are stored in and display it on the page. So the info from ID number 1 in the database should display on a row with 1.jpeg from the directory of images.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - so simple in the end just created a variable from the ID and used that in the image path. i.e. Images/$id.jpg